# Finding a valid bivariate distribution

Tags: self-study, bivariate

For each of the following functions, determine the constant $c$ so that $f(x,y)$ satisfies the conditions of being a joint pmf for two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$:

**(c)** $f(x,y) = c$; $x$ and $y$ are integers such that $6 \leq x+y \leq 8, 0 \leq y \leq 5$

The back of the book says $c = 1/18$, but I don't understand how to get there. I know I'm supposed to set the sum over $x$ and $y$ equal to 1 and solve for $c$, but I don't get how to do that since there is no $x$ or $y$ in the pmf?

edit: I've come up with this. I'm not sure if it's relevant or not, but it's the only way I can see $c = 1/18$ make sense.

> There are 6 possible values for $y$: 0,1,2,3,4,5. Since $x + y$ has a range of 3, $x$ has 3 possible values for each $y$. For example, if $y=0, x=6,7,8 \dots$ if $y=5$, $x=1,2,3$. So in total, 18 values for $x$.

But I don't know what to do with that information...

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. It should be tagged as "self-study."

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of that. Made the change.

Comment: So what is the sum of f(x,y) over these 18 combinations of x and y?  What does that sum need to be in order for f(x,y) to be a joint pmf? Therefore, what does c need to be?

Comment: So since f(x,y) is a constant which means the probability for each of those combinations is the same, and f(x,y) = 1, that it would just be 18c = 1, and c=1/18?

Comment: Given that I believe you meant "sum of f(x,y) = 1", yes.

Comment: Rather than "18 values for $x$", it's in total 18 values for $(x,y)$. In cases like these, if all else fails, draw a picture; however in this case you seem to have essentially arrived at the solution already in your question; you have 18 values each with probability $c$, that must add to 1. Perhaps you could outline the approach to the solution in an answer.